# React Router - navigating within the same component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two routes that uses one component:

```
  <Route path="/category/:slug"
    component={Archives}
    onEnter={ enter }
    onChange={ change }
  />
  <Route path="/tag/:slug"
    component={Archives}
    onEnter={ enter }
    onChange={ change }
  />
```

My problem is, when I click on one of those, they work. But when I am inside and click on another one, they don't. `onChange` and `onEnter` events are working.

I've tried using `componentDidUpdate` and changing the state there (and forcing rendering), but it turned out this is somewhat illegal (as it produces infinite loop).

Comment: Right, react-router understands that you're attempting to transition to the same component, and thus will not unmount and remount it, because there is no need.  What is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I make an AJAX request there, so when I move from `category/one` to `category/two` content changes, but the component doesn't reload.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you posted the code for your component as well.  My understanding is that you'd want to get the response from your request, and set some sort of state, which will trigger the `render` function in your component, showing you the new data.  Is this the part that is not working?

Comment: How did you solved this?